# How do I get the current location in react native expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, location, openweathermap

I want to get the current weather in react native expo app. But I need my current location to implement, so I'm using Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({})and I'm getting errors like "Error requesting location permission","Not authorized to use location services"

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchWeatherData = async (latitude, longitude) => {
          try {
            const response = await fetch(
              'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherlat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=3d9b9b12834e4fca69c88401aeb73c2e'
            );
            const json = await response.json();
            setWeatherData(json);
            console.log(weatherData.main.temp)
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching weather data:', error);
          }
        };
        
        const getLocation = async () => {
            try {
              const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                {
                  title: 'Location Permission',
                  message: 'WeatherApp needs access to your location for fetching weather data.',
                  buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
                  buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                  buttonPositive: 'OK',
                }
              );
      
              if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
                console.log(location)
                fetchWeatherData(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);

              } else {
                setLocationError('Location permission denied');
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error requesting location permission:', error);
            }
          };
      
          getLocation();

    }, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are handling permission requests only for Android but if you are targeting the iOS platform the above implementation don't handle that edge-case on iOS.

It's recommended to use `expo-location` to handle permission and location access simultaneously on both platform.

Let's refactor code as below:

```js
import * as Location from "expo-location";

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchWeatherData = async (latitude, longitude) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherlat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=3d9b9b12834e4fca69c88401aeb73c2e"
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      setWeatherData(json);
      console.log(weatherData.main.temp);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching weather data:", error);
    }
  };

  const getLocation = async () => {
    try {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();

      if (status !== "granted") {
        setLocationError("Location permission denied");
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      fetchWeatherData(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error requesting location permission:", error);
    }
  };

  getLocation();
}, []);
```